# Can MassTransit IBus safely be used in Consumers

Tags: masstransit

I would like to use the same service classes in both the publisher (which will be a REST API) and consumer. Since sending messages can be a part of these service classes, they have an instance of `IBus` injected into them so they can publish/send messages. This is fine on the REST API side, but the MassTransit documentation states the following:

> Once you have consumers you will ALWAYS use `ConsumeContext` to interact with the bus, and never the `IBus`.

What's the reason behind this? Is it just performance related or does using `IBus` have any other consequences? And what are the alternatives to doing this? Would injecting `IPublishEndpoint` and `ISendEndpointProvider` be the accepted solution here, or does that not really change anything?

The reason why I want to do this is because some actions can be done either synchronously by using the API, or happen automatically in the background by using a message, and having to duplicate the business logic would be very inconvenient and hard to maintain.

**Bonus question:** The documentation states the same thing for `TransactionalBus`:

> Never use the TransactionalBus or TransactionalEnlistmentBus when writing consumers. These tools are very specific and should be used only in the scenarios described.

However, if I want to support transactions in the above mentioned services, I will probably have to use `TransactionalBus`, but is it safe to do so in consumers? I do know about the in-memory outbox, but I have 2 problems with it:

1. It can only be used on the consumer side, so the publisher would not support transactions
2. It does not support "partial transactions" - the codebase that I'm working on has certain places where transactions don't wrap the entire API call, but rather only parts of it, so cases where some entities are successfully written to the database before the transaction is even started can happen, and in these cases the corresponding messages would need to be sent/published as well. This could easily be done by calling `Release` on the `TransactionalBus` at the right time, but couldn't be done when using the outbox since it's all or nothing (if an exception happens, nothing will be sent).

This bonus question isn't that important since I could probably work around it, but is still something I'm curious about, as it could be resolved by using `TransactionalBus` (if that won't cause any issues in consumers).

Comment: Only one question at a time, please. [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using `IPublishEndpoint` or `ISendEndpointProvider` to publish or send messages from your components and/or services. There is almost never a reason to use `IBus`.

`IPublishEndpoint` and `ISendEndpointProvider` are registered a scoped, so a valid scope is required. In a service that normally doesn't have a scope, one can easily be created using `provider.CreateScope()`. Scopes should also be disposed of when they are no longer used.

**Note that current versions** should use `provider.CreateAsyncScope()` instead, and to make it easy just assign it using:

```cs
await using var scope = provider.CreateAsyncScope()

var publishEndpoint = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<IPublishEndpoint>();
```

For any components, consumers, etc. simply use constructor injection for either of those two types, and they will resolve the proper services depending upon the context.

> Also, don't use `ITransactionBus`. The new outbox is a better solution, as it's actually in the transaction. I will eventually remove `ITransactionBus` from MassTransit.

Comment: The transactional outbox actually solves my problem perfectly... I spent so much time looking into TransactionalBus and InMemoryOutbox and completely overlooked the one that I needed. Just using `AddEntityFrameworkOutbox` does the work without needing to add other code.

Thank you for the quick response!